# Polyland Wordpress Output a drop-down list headed by the current language

Tags: php, css, wordpress, polylang

I want to create a drop-down menu in my site header. I use this code:

```
<ul class="lang" id="top-lang">
  <li class="pll-parent-menu-item"><a href="#pll_switcher"><?php echo pll_current_language( 'name' ) ?></a> 
    <ul class="sub-menu">
     <?php if(function_exists('pll_the_languages')){ 
        pll_the_languages(array('display_names_as' => 'name', 'hide_current' => 1, 'show_flags'=>1)); 
     } ?> 
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But I don't understand why, the current language is output without a flag.

I thought maybe I could just display a list of languages, but it's not clear how to make the active language appear in the title of the drop-down menu

Answer (score 0):

you have `'hide_current' => 1` set which hides the current language if set to 1 (true). by default it is set to 0 (false).